# wp_remote_get in scheduled event action returns wp login page

Tags: plugins, wp-remote-get

I have a plugin that triggers an action from a scheduled event. In this action, i simply want to visit a url - an address pointing to a method on my plugin. However, using `wp_remote_get`, the request returns the html of the wordpress login page. This would make sense if i were not logged in, but i am, and if i simply type the url in to the browser, there is no need to log in (already logged in from wordpress) and everything works as intended. I don't actually need the page content / markup - just for the url to be visited, which will trigger an action.

Is there any way to send the request from the current session, or the logged in user, or something?

My code:

```
function my_action()
{
    $url = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'public/index.php?action=do-my-action';
    error_log('calling url');
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    error_log('response obtained');
    if( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
        error_log('error');
        error_log($response['body']);
    } else {
        error_log('response ok');
        error_log($response['body']);
    }
}


if (! wp_next_scheduled ( 'my_event'))
{
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'weekly', 'my_event');
}

add_action( 'my_event', 'my_action');
```

Comment: Why not call the plugin method directly in code instead of  via http self request?

Comment: You’re logged in, but you’re not the one visiting the page, are you. WordPress on the server is, and it’s not going to be logged in.

Comment: Ok, is there any way i can send the logged-in users credentials with the request?